# Keras isn't using Theano

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano

1- I create a virtual env: `mkvirtualenv kerasTH`

2- I install keras using `pip install keras`

3- That's the output for `pip list`

```
Package       Version
------------- -------
h5py          2.10.0
joblib        0.16.0
Keras         2.4.3
numpy         1.19.1
Pillow        7.2.0
pip           20.2.2
PyYAML        5.3.1
scikit-learn  0.23.2
scipy         1.5.2
setuptools    49.6.0
six           1.15.0
Theano        1.0.5
threadpoolctl 2.1.0
wheel         0.35.1
```

When I run `python` and then `import keras` I get this error `` ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow` ``

I edited the `.keras/keras.json` file to have the following:

```
{
    "image_dim_ordering": "th",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "theano"
}
```

I used

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
```

Used `KERAS_BACKEND='theano' python script.py` but I am still getting the same error. Not sure how to switch to theano, any suggestions ?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Python 3.8.2
pip 20.2.2
CUDA Version: 11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keras 2.4 is actually just a wrapper on top of `tf.keras`, meaning that it does not support multiple backends, only the TensorFlow backend.

So you would need to use Keras 2.3, which does still support multiple backends.

Comment: wow thank you for that, I should've checked the versions and their github releases page: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases