# How to switch keras backend from tenserflow to theano?

Tags: python, keras

I need keras for my work, it needs tenserflow but I'm operating Windows 32. So I decided to switch keras backend. I created json file in "C/USERS/admin/.keras" it looks like:

```
{
"image_data_format":"channels first",
"epsilon": 1e-07,
"floatx": "float32",
"backend": "theano"
}
```

I try to import keras but the problem the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLaef.png)

Comment: Also I have installed "theano".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should I change anything in init.py?

```
try:
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError(
        'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
        'Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`')

from . import utils
from . import activations
from . import applications
from . import backend
from . import datasets
from . import engine
from . import layers
from . import preprocessing
from . import wrappers
from . import callbacks
from . import constraints
from . import initializers
from . import metrics
from . import models
from . import losses
from . import optimizers
from . import regularizers

# Also importable from root
from .layers import Input
from .models import Model
from .models import Sequential
```

Comment: the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587843/keras-isnt-using-theano